# I suddently can't press buttons in my game anymore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, 2d

I almost finished my game. After I added a UI as the health bar of the enemy, everything went wrong.
All of my buttons (from selecting tower to the game over scene's buttons) are unavailable to interact.
Although my code didn't change anything that related to it.

I don't know what was the problem. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you have an EventSystem in scene?

Comment: can you provide more details?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What about remove that healthbar again / undo your latest changes.. In general I would strongly recommend to use any version control - e.g. GIT .. otherwise you won't come far in your coding life ;)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you added a transparent Canvas with a `GraphicRaycaster` which is intercepting all your inputs.

`GraphicRaycaster` makes it so the Canvas can receive input events.
That combined with the `SortOrder` can stop these events to be passed down to other Canvases.

You can either remove the `GraphicRaycaster` from this new Canvas showing the health bar, or set `RaycastTarget = false` on every Image that shouldn't intercept input events.